# How to keep fields values after submit in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a form and I would like to keep the values of the fields after a click on submit. How can I do this?

Views.py :

```py
if request.method == "POST":
    form = MyForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
else:
    form = MyForm()
```

template.html

```html
<form method="post" id="Myform" >
    {{form}}
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" >
</form>
```

Comment: what do you mean by keeping the field values?

Answer (score 1):

Moving initial form assignment outside the check for the POST method should do.

```
form = MyForm(request.POST or None)
if request.method == "POST":
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
```